# whether $ \pi_1 \ $ is one-to-one or onto

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $ \ S \subseteq A \times B \ $ be  a function (set of ordered pairs ) and $ \pi_1 : S \to A \ $ , $ \pi_2: S \to B \ $ be the projection maps.  Then conclude **whether $ \pi_1 \ $ is one-to-one or onto .**

**Answer:**

**I know that both $ \pi_1 \ and \ \pi_2 \ $ are onto map  but I can not prove it.**

**Also I can not conclude whether $ \pi_1 , \ \pi_2 \ $ are one-to-one or not.**

**please help me out**

Comment: FYI: I’m down-voting this for the poor formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh.... why can't the phone app let you delete your posts?

Okay, as long as I can't delete.  Use the definition of functions.

By definition, for any $x\in A $ the is exactly one $f (x) $ so $\pi_1 (x,f (x))=x $ are distinct and existant, so $\pi_1 $ is both 1-1 and onto.

But nothing of the sort can be said about $\pi_2 (x,f (x))=f (x)\in B $.

$\pi_2$ is 1-1 and/or onto if and $f$ is.

Comment: thank you sir. I really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

$\{(1,2),(3,2)\}$ is a subset of $\{1,3\}\times\{4,2\}$

Is $\pi_2$ onto? Is it one-to-one?

Comment: would you clear  the steps little more because i am not getting

Comment: Just check to see? The steps are understanding the definitions of onto and one-to-one. If these are the issue, study a little, or see your professor.

Comment: So you mean here , $ S=\{(1,2), \ (3,2) \}  \ and \ \ A=\{1,3 \} , \ \ B=\{4,2 \} $ . Next , $ \pi_2 : S \to A \times B \ $ is defined by $ \pi_2(1,2)=2 , \ \ \pi_2(3,2)=2 \  \Rightarrow \pi_2(1,2)=\pi_2(3,2) \ $ . So $ \pi_2 \ $ is not one one . Am I right ?

Comment: fleablood''s answer is better. I would accept his/hers.